# insert based on condition check in similar columns between 2 tables and add NULL when missing SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
CREATE TABLE #temppayload(
            [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [field_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [field_value_string] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
            [field_value_numeric] [float] NULL,
            [field_value_date] [date] NULL,
            [field_value_bool] [bit] NULL,
            [field_value_lookup] [int] NULL
            )
        
            insert into #temppayload values (1,31,1,'NEW',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
            insert into #temppayload values (1,11,1,'Update1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
            insert into #temppayload values (1,12,2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'4')
        
            insert into #temppayload values (4,41,4,Null,'1',NULL,NULL,NULL)
        
            CREATE TABLE #tempdb(
            [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [field_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [field_value_string] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
            [field_value_numeric] [float] NULL,
            [field_value_date] [date] NULL,
            [field_value_bool] [bit] NULL,
            [field_value_lookup] [int] NULL
            )
        
            insert into #tempdb values (1,11,1,'create1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
            insert into #tempdb values (1,12,2, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
            insert into #tempdb values (1,13,3,NULL,NULL,'2020-04-15',NULL,NULL)      
                  
            insert into #tempdb values (4,41,4,NULL,'1',NULL,NULL,NULL)
        
        
        
            user_id   field_id    type_id  [field_value_string]   [field_value_numeric]  [field_value_date] [field_value_bool] [field_value_lookup]
             1          31          1             NEW                 NULL                   NULL                NULL             NULL
             1          11          1             update1             NULL                  NULL                 NULL             NULL
             1          12          2             NULL                NULL                  NULL                 NULL               4
             1          13          3             NULL                NULL                  NULL                 NULL              NULL
```

condition

- new value from payload
- value change compared to payload and tempdb
- insert with null when #temppayload does not have it but exist in #tempdb

i was thinking of doing not exist seperately, left join seperately  and union both the result.
Adding condition like below , the approach does not look efficient to me. i tried with innerjoin and leftjoin together could not figure out.

Any help is much appreciated . Thanks in advance.

```
select 
  distinct 
  st.user_id
  ,st.field_id
  ,st.type_id
  ,st.field_value_string
  ,st.field_value_numeric
  ,st.field_value_date
  ,st.field_value_bool
  ,st.field_value_lookup 
from #temppayload st
where not exists (select * 
                  from #tempdb t 
                  where st.user_id = t.user_id 
                    AND st.type_id = t.type_id 
                    AND st.field_id = t.field_id 
                    AND st.field_value_string = t.field_value_string 
                    AND st.field_value_string IS NULL 
                    AND t.field_value_string Is NULL
```

Comment: your code doesn't work, and the tbake names are not mysql compatible, did you tag the database wrong?

Comment: @nbk i am using sql .should work though. you can uuse this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0f07eebb06f7b5d215bc616fd03bcc6

Comment: This isn't MySQL. Is this actually Microsoft SQL Server? Each dialect has **considerable** differences in syntax and structure.

Comment: @tadman sorry yes microsoft SQL server. i was not clear in the question. my apology

Answer (score 0):

Able to figure this out by below approach . feel free to share if there is any other efficient way to do this.

```
select * into #modifiedpayload FROM
(select distinct st.user_id,st.field_id,st.type_id,st.field_value_string,st.field_value_numeric,st.field_value_date,st.field_value_lookup from 
#temppayload st
where not exists (select user_id,st.field_id,st.type_id,st.field_value_string,field_value_numeric from #tempdb 
                     where st.user_id = user_id 
                                    AND st.type_id = type_id 
                                    AND st.field_id = field_id                              
                                    AND (st.field_value_string IS NULL AND  field_value_string IS NULL OR st.field_value_string = field_value_string)
                                    AND (st.field_value_numeric IS NULL AND  field_value_numeric IS NULL OR st.field_value_numeric = field_value_numeric)
                                    AND (st.field_value_date IS NULL AND  field_value_date IS NULL OR st.field_value_date = field_value_date)
                                    AND (st.field_value_bool IS NULL AND  field_value_bool IS NULL OR st.field_value_bool = field_value_bool)
                                    AND (st.field_value_lookup IS NULL AND  field_value_lookup IS NULL OR st.field_value_lookup = field_value_lookup)
                                    )
UNION 
  select t.user_id,t.field_id,t.type_id, NULL as field_value_string, NULL as field_value_numeric, NULL as field_value_date, NULL field_value_lookup from #tempdb  t
  LEFT JOIN #temppayload s
    on t.user_id = s.user_id AND t.field_id = s.field_id
    where s.field_id IS NULL ) AS X
```